# How do I make relative importing work in Python using Eclipse with PyDev?

Tags: python, eclipse, svn, pydev

So I am working on a Python project that was here before me in an SVN repo. When I first pulled it, the structure was a bit odd due to the fact that it was similar to:

```
Proj\
    src\
    tags\
    trunk\
```

And then everything is inside src\ are the python module files except src\ turns out to just be a logical folder with no overall package inside. There isn't a __init__.py in the project anywhere. So I want to restructure it at least so I can use relative imports through my project. I also want to set it up so it looks more like this.

```
Proj\
    src\
        model\
        controller\
        view\
        test\
    tags\
    trunk\
```

However, I tried setting this up and no matter what I seem to do, it cannot resolve the relative import the moment I have to traverse packages. I placed a __init__.py file in each level package including one inside the src\ folder with all of them having __all__ defined. However, when I try to make a unit test in my test\ package and do an import saying:

```
from ..model.foo import Foo
```

to attempt to import the Foo class from module foo.py located inside of the model package, it doesn't resolve. Just in case it was a problem specifically with unit tests, I also tried this with a module in the controller package that was dependent on a class in the model package and vice versa. None of them worked. How do I resolve this?

Comment: When you say it doesn't resolve, you mean that you have an error when running the module or you have an error in PyDev?

Comment: I am assuming right now it is an error running the module, but I didn't want to rule out the possibility that maybe it is some sort of PyDev config problem.

Comment: Can you post the exception you're having?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you added the root folder to your system path?

```
import sys
sys.path.append(<place the Proj dir here>)
```

then you could import as follows:

```
from src.model.somefile import Something
```

If you don't know the absolute path for Proj, you can always use combinations such as

```
os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())
```

Comment: I think you mean `os.getcwd()`